# How to set post_max_size on apache server with htaccess (getting internal server error)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, post

I am trying to increase the maximum post size limit on my server.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

However it does not seem to work and throws a 500 Internal server error.

Any ideas why this could be happening and how to overcome this?

Comment: Typically, you'll get a description of the error in Apache error logs.

Comment: There is nothing in there apart from 404 errors for, ironically 404.html page

Comment: ¿Where is the htaccess file? It has to be in the root directory.

Comment: Hmmm... And do you run PHP as Apache module, rather than CGI?

Comment: The same error occurs no matter where the .htaccess is.
Agh, I do run it as CGI as it turned out.. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your syntax is correct. However, the `php_value` Apache directive is provided by the `mod_php` module. If you don't run PHP as Apache module (e.g., it runs as FastCGI or with some other SAPI) that directive won't be defined, thus the 500 error.

There're many ways to [change PHP settings](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php). In practice, I've found that hosting services that run CGI often provide a custom `php.ini` file somewhere in your FTP account. Additionally, if you run PHP/5.3.0 or newer you can use [`.user.ini` files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php). Last but not least, there's [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set) within code.