# Symfony2 ParameterBag limit?

Tags: php, symfony, post

I have encountered a pretty weird bug. I am trying to submit an array containing 290 items with each 5 properties serialized in JSON to my server.

For an unknown reason when I output the count of the request server side it's only 200.

I tried to simply output $_POST to see if there was a difference but the number of item is the same (200). After some research I found that it might be post_max_size config but it is set to 128M.

I can confirm using the chrome dev tool that the data sent exceeds the 200 items received by the server.

Thanks for your time

Comment: How much is max_input_vars?

Comment: 1000. Hum maybe it could be that!

Comment: @ZsoltGyöngyösi nope :( tried to put it to 10000 still 200.

Comment: Maybe a config on your Php server ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14125295/2454790

Comment: @YenneInfo All of the above are checked and cleared from my list. I maxed all of them.

Comment: Did you check all these parameters with `php_info()`? Maybe it is overrode in another place?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Indeed the max_input_vars is back to 1000 instead of 10000.

Comment: try to restart your apache after editing `php.ini`

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov There we go :D I added in the .htaccess the 
php_value max_input_vars 10000 and it did the trick!!! You can write it as an answer if you want I'll accept it.

Comment: I think that this question has to be deleted because it has no value for community.