# PHP $_Post doesn't work with large inputs. (Probably lack of memory)

Tags: php, apache, memory

Ive an apache webserver, running the following php.

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['Message'])){
   $var = $_POST['Message'];
   file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
   header("Location: https://google.ru");
    exit();
    }
?>
```

Basically it takes the submited message from a field, and posts it into a .txt file. It works fine with small inputs (20-30 characters) . But it crashes with more than that.
I've checked the apache/php error.log but theres nothing interesting or related with apache..
I only have those logs errors from apache access.log

```
"POST /executable.php HTTP/1.1" 200 215 "https://randomsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.0.xxx.333 Safari/537.36"
```

I checked wheres php.ini to modify post_size and max_memory located , and it gave me 2 results

```
    /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

I modified in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
max_execution_time 300 
 post_max_size = 500M 
 memory limit = 1024M
```

Still not working, and only small inputs get posted to the data.txt file.

EDIT:
I modified the script to check errors

```
 <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    if(!empty($_POST['Message'])){
   $var = $_POST['Message'];
   file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
   header("Location: https://google.ru");
    exit();
    }
?>
```

now in errors.log i have

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /var/www/example.com/executable.php on line 2, referer: https://example.com/
```

EDIT2: SECCOND ATEMPT (not working)

```
   <?php  ini_set('post_max_size', '300M');
    if(!empty($_POST['Message'])){
   $var = $_POST['Message'];
   file_put_contents("data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
   header("Location: https://google.ru");
    exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script and run again. Should report any errors/warning.

Comment: below <?php ? or above it? however ive tried adding it below. Where are the errors supposed to be logged? /var/log/apache2/error.log hasnt changed after that implementation

Comment: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1)`... the notices are displayed in your rendered PHP page.

Comment: edited main post

Comment: Add a trailing semicolon to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to fix that new error...

Comment: nothing changes, no new errors displayed. i noticed that if i repeat the smae letter in the post form like forever, it will work in the input , but if i set different characters it doesnt work

Comment: im checking /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to .htaccess file

> php_value post_max_size 30M

This usually happens with php 5.3 or less.

If you dont have .htacess file create one under your application root folder

And if you have added the same in php.ini , try restarting the server.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: should the .htaccess have something special inside apart of that instructions?

Comment: not necessary, just add this line for now , will see. Which version of Php are you using ?? you can refer to this thread for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125295/how-to-set-post-max-size-on-apache-server-with-htaccess-getting-internal-server

Comment: Tried everything u said (including restarting the server) , nothing worked.

Comment: Okay, Which version of Php are you using ??

Comment: 5.6.30-0+deb8u1

Comment: Okay, please try adding this ini_set('post_max_size', '300M') on top of your function /file

Comment: nothing changes, I noticed that i can input a lot of equal characters (ddddddddddddddddddddddd) for example, but if i input (dabecasdawddcawe) it crashes.

Comment: crash!! okay, can you to put your code in try/catch block and output exception object to get the actually issue causing the  exception